Intuition behind terms in Chinese Remainder Theorem solution formula
Given the following equations: $$ a = 2 \ (mod \ 5)$$ and $$ a = 3 \ (mod \ 13)$$
Let $a_1=2$, $a_2=3$, $n_1=5$, $n_2=13$, $m_1=13$, $m_2=5$
Let $m=5 \times 13=65$
Let $$c_i = m_i * (m^{-1}_i mod \ n_i) $$ giving $$c_1 = 13 \cdot (2 \ mod \ 5) = 26$$ and $$c_2 = 5 \cdot (8 \ mod \ 13) = 40$$
Then
$$a = 2 \cdot 26 + 3 \cdot 40 = 42 \ (mod \ 65)$$
How to interpret what $c_i$ denotes (intuitively)?
Also, how to resolve the following technical interpretation?
My understanding of equation containing $mod \ n$ is to view the given equation within a new frame of reference: a number system of symbols ranging from $0$ to $n-1$. I don't know how to interpret $c_i$ where only one term of the equation has $mod \ n$ frame of reference specified rather than entire equation.
Visualization:
In the picture below you can see how $a$ changes by $c_1$ steps (mod 65) varies as you change $a_1$ by 1 and same goes for the columns which is how solution is defined per Chinese Remainder theorem.


Your $c_1$ has two properties under mod $n_1$ and $n_2$: 1) $c_1 \equiv m_1 \cdot \left(m_1^{-1}\bmod n_1\right) \equiv 1 \pmod {n_1}$; and 2) $c_1 \equiv m_1 \cdot(\ldots) \equiv n_2 \cdot(\ldots)\equiv 0\pmod{n_2}$.
